# why my own package does not in the GOROOT

Tags: go, package

I am a beginner at GO, and try to run my first project.
And I have the problem to import my own package.
I create go project under go/src.
And the file structure is below:

```
- projectName
     - function
       - utils
          helper.go( package utils)
   main.go(package main)
```

And I want to import utils in the main

```
import (
    "projectName/function/utils"
)
```

Give me the error that could not import projectName/function/utils (cannot find package "projectName/function/utils" in any of
/usr/local/go/src/projectName/function/utils (from $GOROOT)
/Users/myUser/go/src/projectName/function/utils (from $GOPATH)

And I created the project exactly under /Users/myUser/go/src/ folder.
More information:
go.mod is created under /Users/myUser/go/src/projectName
And the content is:

```
module projectName


go 1.16
```

if I run "go mod tidy", it will throw the error:

```
projectName imports
        projectName/function/utils: package projectName/function/utils is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/projectName/function/utils)
```

Comment: @Brist Thanks, I follow the tutorial and init the go.mod. but still can't import the package. Shall I do something for the until package?

Comment: Sorry - deleted my comment because it looks like you have `GO111MODULE` to `auto`.  However the point remains that as a beginner you should be using modules as set out in the [tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) because support for `GOPATH` is likely to be [dropped in 1.17](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes). As @CeriseLimón says more info is needed to assist.

Comment: @CeriseLimón question has updated

Comment: Here's code as described in the question: https://play.golang.org/p/eeAoVBvCNJv It compiles and runs.  How does it differ from what you have?

Comment: @CeriseLimón it's the same.

Comment: Edit the question to show the output of `go env` and the output of `go install` when run from the directory `/Users/myUser/go/src/projectName`.

Comment: If you’re just starting and you run into a problem like this, the best course of action is often to start over, and follow the documentation again, exactly. We know “How to Write Go Code” works if you follow it step by step, and without double checking every possible detail you’ve done, all we are doing is guessing and quoting the same documentation. Once you have a working setup, then move slowly from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a new project, please run go `mod init projectName`, otherwise, you can't import the package.
Please don't skip this step.

Comment: You were not getting guidance to `go mod init projectName` because you said that you created the go.mod file and that your code is identical to the playground example with a go.mod file.